# isolate blue color

Tags: javascript, image, opencv, colors, objective-c++

I'd like to extract specific colors from an image using **OpenCV & objc++**, so I followed this [tutorial](https://solderspot.wordpress.com/2014/10/18/using-opencv-for-simple-object-detection/). A big part of the "algorithm" is already working but it still comes to some issues:

> *This is my image where I'd like to extract different color areas:*
>   [image]

---

On the image there should be applied a simple color extraction to just get the right colored ares *(in one case just the red areas, and in another can just the blue cube)*.

**Using my code (I've added below) this is the result I get extracting the red cube:**

[image: img]

But it seems like I couldn't find a working way to extract different colors *(like extracting only the blue cube)*

See my code for the red cube extraction:

```
cv::Scalar   min(220/2, 190, 80);
cv::Scalar   max(260/2, 255, 255);
cv::Mat threshold_frame;
cv::inRange( tempMatHSV, min, max, threshold_frame);

cv::Mat str_el = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3));
morphologyEx(threshold_frame, threshold_frame, cv::MORPH_OPEN, str_el);
morphologyEx(threshold_frame, threshold_frame, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, str_el);
```

Any help how to edit the **scalar-parameters** to get a blue color matching would be very appreciated

Comment: What steps have you taken to detect blue color ?

Comment: I've just **edited the min-max parameters** to the blue HSV color values but it doesn't seems working because no blue color gets detected- the image is fully black! @ZdaR

Comment: It's strange that exactly the same values of the min and max in the tutorial and your code give different results. In the tutorial, these values are used for retrieve blue colour, but your code retrieves red colour. Are you sure that provided code produces provided mask? 220 - 260 hue values are for blue, not for red.

Answer (score 0):

Hue contains main colour information.
I would recommend starting with these ranges of Hue for colours (OpenCV format):

```
Red - Hue [0 - 30] and [150 - 180]
Green - Hue [30 - 90]
Blue - Hue [90 - 150]
```

while setting Saturation and Value to the full range of [0 - 255]

Then you can experiment with Saturation and Value to fit the illumination conditions.